# jQuery loop within a loop

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that processes an 2D array:

```
var len = result.DATA.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  thickness = result.DATA[i][2];
  finish = result.DATA[i][1];
  colorName = result.DATA[i][0];
  color = '<div class="colorName"> + colorName + </div>
}
```

I have different finishes for colors, so for ex: Finish: Matte, I have 3 colors, for leather, I have 5. I want to run a loop inside for loop so I can group colors by finish. Not sure what would be the best way to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

So basically, it should show like this:

1. Matte
   a. red
   b. green
2. Leather
   a. blue
   b. yellow
   c. orange

Comment: Create a 2nd array for each finish. In you loop you then check if you already have the current finish in the 2nd array, if not, create a new entry for the finish and then add the current color to either the existing or the newly created finish.

Comment: Be aware there is no such thing as a "jQuery loop" -- **for** is part of "vanilla" JavaScript. If you google "javascript nested for loop" instead you'll find good examples, such as http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/nesting-loops.asp. Actually, I don't see any jQuery in your example at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create an object with the different finishes, and loop through the object properties to create the output.

```js
let out = {};
let data = [["red","matte"],["blue","leather"],["orange","leather"],["green","matte"],["yellow","leather"]];
let list = document.getElementById("list");

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let finish = data[i][1];
  let colorName = data[i][0];
  
  if (!out[finish])
    out[finish] = [];
  
  out[finish].push(colorName);
}

for(let prop in out) {
  let html = prop + ": ";
  html += out[prop].join(", ") + "<br/>";
  list.innerHTML += html;
}
```

```html
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: finishes are dynamic and it comes from db query, so I didn't want to create an object with different finishes, since there might be a possibility of changing that in future

Comment: No problem with that--this code is completely dynamic too. Try changing one of the finishes in the `data`--it will output on a separate line.

Comment: so basically you are saying for me since its dynamic, data = [finish, color] and I might need to convert array to list or something to have it the format as yours.

Comment: I'm saying that JavaScript objects are convenient when trying to group data. I've provided a running snippet on how this might work. Is there something you need that isn't handled by the code I've provided? If so, what exactly is lacking? If you can clarify then I can help you further.